# Load website with webview only give errors

Tags: android, android-webview

**I have this code in Java file called Principal :**

```
package com.vistaweb.vistaweb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
    }

}
```

**My Layout it´s called :** activity_principal.xml and refered rightly

But all time give me errors i think it´s ok but when run emulator don´t show nothing ang give me errors as for example **cannot find symbol webview** , etc

Which it´s the problem ? , thank´s for the help , Regard

**I see these errors :**

```
C:\Users\pol\Desktop\VistaWeb\app\src\main\java\com\vistaweb\vistaweb\Principal.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        ^
  symbol:   class WebView
  location: class Principal
C:\Users\pol\Desktop\VistaWeb\app\src\main\java\com\vistaweb\vistaweb\Principal.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                             ^
  symbol:   class WebView
  location: class Principal
C:\Users\pol\Desktop\VistaWeb\app\src\main\java\com\vistaweb\vistaweb\Principal.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable webView
  location: class id
C:\Users\pol\Desktop\VistaWeb\app\src\main\java\com\vistaweb\vistaweb\Principal.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        ^
  symbol:   class WebSettings
  location: class Principal
C:\Users\pol\Desktop\VistaWeb\app\src\main\java\com\vistaweb\vistaweb\Principal.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                                       ^
  symbol:   class WebViewClient
  location: class Principal
5 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.423 secs
```

Comment: could you write your logcat or the error shown in android studio

Comment: Yes i add some errors in the questions , regards

Comment: you have to import webview `import android.webkit.WebView;`

Comment: make sure you enable autoImport in android studio, to avoid that kind of silly errors.

Comment: And please how i do this , i start in this no many time ago , thank´s

Answer (score 1):

Add required imports

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

or Alternately android studio show the options while typing so if you choose an option by pressing enter , the import is automatically added for you

or
you can use `ctrl+space` , use the import option to add the import automatically

Comment: Yes perfect now the only error it´s this findViewById(R.id.webview); show error in only this line and tell me cannot resolve symbol webview

Comment: @Jose post the xml file code  `activity_principal` , make sure your webview has an id like `android:id="@+id/webView"`  in XML , if yes then try re-build  your project